# Trigger a method before navigation? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am using the following code to execute the createUser method, which updates var self.auth.user (a user's ID). I am trying to pass self.auth.user to ProfileBuilderView **after** it has been updated.

```
NavigationLink(destination: ProfileBuilderView(userId: self.auth.user)) {
                    Text("Sign Up")
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                    self.auth.createUser(email: self.email, password: self.password)
                })
```

Right now, createUser is triggered after navigation, and the previous user's Id is passed to ProfileBuilderView. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549272/14351818